# GTA V Premium Edition won’t let me play online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My GTA V Premium Edition won’t let me play online. It supposedly comes with free online play but it keeps telling me to pay $10.

Comment: What is the exact message you are receiving?

Answer (score 8):

Xbox requires Xbox Live to play online and PS4 requires PS+. On PC you should be able to play online without any extra subscriptions.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just email rockstar games and say that’s happening

Comment: While that is helpful, getting a response can take a long time. He's looking for the reason why this problem is happening and how to fix it.